# How does the storeAs ... triggeredBy work in simple-build-tool?

Tags: scala, sbt

There are SBT TaskKeys that uses `storeAs` and `triggeredBy` routines.

There are 3 parts:

*A* storeAs *B* triggeredBy *C*

I suspect that it is like

store `findManifestPath` to `manifestPackageName` when `manifestPath` task complete

But why we couldn't write `manifestPackageName <<= findManifestPath` ?

Few samples

```
manifestPackageName <<= findManifestPath storeAs manifestPackageName triggeredBy manifestPath
```

or

```
multiJvmTestNames <<= multiJvmTests map { _.keys.toSeq } storeAs multiJvmTestNames triggeredBy compile
```

or

```
discoveredMainClasses <<= compile map discoverMainClasses storeAs discoveredMainClasses triggeredBy compile
```

or

```
definedTestNames <<= definedTests map ( _.map(_.name).distinct) storeAs definedTestNames triggeredBy compile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`storeAs` is really only intended as an internal API at this time, but it persists the result of evaluating a task so that it can be retrieved later.  The examples above, for example, are used by parsers for tab completion.  You can't evaluate tasks during parsing, so this is the approach taken.

`triggeredBy` is a way to schedule a command to run even if it isn't a dependency of anything.  It is mainly for executing side effects when another task runs.  In the case `definedTestNames`, this ensures that the names are persisted whenever `test:compile` runs.